# Drop a specific row in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I tried drop method of `pandas` but I didn't use it. How do I remove a specific row in pandas with Python?

e.g.: My specific row is => Name: Bertug  Grade: A  Age: 15

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Jhon',15,'A'],['Anna',19,'B'],['Paul',25,'D']])
df. columns = ['Name','Age','Grade']

df
Out[472]: 
   Name  Age Grade
0  Jhon   15     A
1  Anna   19     B
2  Paul   25     D
```

You can get the index of your row:

```
i = df[((df.Name == 'jhon') &( df.Age == 15) & (df.Grade == 'A'))].index
```

and then drop it:

```
df.drop(i)
Out[474]: 
   Name  Age Grade
1  Anna   19     B
2  Paul   25     D
```

As @jezrael pointed our, you can also just negate all three:

```
df[((df.Name != 'jhon') &( df.Age != 15) & (df.Grade != 'A'))]
Out[477]: 
   Name  Age Grade
1  Anna   19     B
2  Paul   25     D
```

Comment: There's mistake in the negation. The negation of `A and B` is `~A or ~B`. I added an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75444552/19123103) that shows the correct negation.

Answer (score 28):

you can just use :

```
df.drop([a,b,c])
```

where `a,b,c` are the list of indexes or row numbers.

to delete only one particular row use

```
df.drop(i)
```

where `i` is the index or the row number.

Comment: You should assign to the new df, or just add inplace=True in drop command section. Without these, you could not use dropped version.

Answer (score 1):

Dropping rows is the inverse operation of filtering rows you want to **keep**, so a negating a boolean mask that filters for the rows to drop is enough.

```py
df[~(df['Name'].eq('Bertug') & df['Grade'].eq('A') & df['Age'].eq(15))]
```

which is, by [de Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), equivalent to

```py
df[df['Name'].ne('Bertug') | df['Grade'].ne('A') | df['Age'].ne(15))]
```

Another approach is to simply query the rows you want to keep.

```py
df1 = df.query("not (Name == 'Bertug' and Grade == 'A' and Age == 15)")
# or 
df1 = df.query("Name != 'Bertug' or Grade != 'A' or Age != 15")
```

---

If the index of the row(s) to be dropped are given, then `query` (or `drop`) can be used too. For example, the following drops the second row.

```py
idx = [1]
df1 = df.query("index != @idx")

# equivalently,
df1 = df.drop(idx)
```